# issue in including kotlinx-data-time libray in kotlinjs project

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-js

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':packageJson'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':npm'.
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.1.0.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Cannot choose between the following variants of org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.1.0:
> - jsIr-runtime
> - jsLegacy-runtime
> All of them match the consumer attributes:
> - Variant 'jsIr-runtime' capability org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.1.0:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler 'ir' but wasn't required.
> - Compatible attributes:
> - Required org.gradle.usage 'kotlin-runtime' and found compatible value 'kotlin-runtime'.
> - Required org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type 'js' and found compatible value 'js'.
> - Variant 'jsLegacy-runtime' capability org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.1.0:
> - Unmatched attributes:
> - Found org.gradle.status 'release' but wasn't required.
> - Found org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler 'legacy' but wasn't required.
> - Compatible attributes:
> - Required org.gradle.usage 'kotlin-runtime' and found compatible value 'kotlin-runtime'.
> - Required org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type 'js' and found compatible value 'js'.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

Publishing a build scan to scans.gradle.com requires accepting the Gradle Terms of Service defined at https://gradle.com/terms-of-service. Do you accept these terms? [yes, no]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building a project using Kotlin 1.3.xx, you may encounter a Gradle error if one of your dependencies (or any transitive dependency) was built using Kotlin 1.4+:

This resolution problem appears because Kotlin 1.4 introduces the choice between two different compiler backends for Kotlin/JS – a choice that was not available in Kotlin 1.3.xx.

Workaround:

In order to use the libraries, create a file called workaround_to_use_1_4_libs_in_1_3.gradle.kts in the root directory of your project, and add the following code:

```
    val pluginAction: Plugin<*>.() -> Unit = {
    val pluginVersion = try {
        this.javaClass.getMethod("getKotlinPluginVersion").invoke(this) as String
    } catch(e: Exception) { null }
    if (pluginVersion != null && pluginVersion.startsWith("1.3")) {
        val jsCompilerAttr = Attribute.of("org.jetbrains.kotlin.js.compiler", String::class.java)
        project.dependencies.attributesSchema.attribute(jsCompilerAttr) {
            this.disambiguationRules.add(KotlinJsCompilerDisambiguationRule::class.java)
        }
    }
}
project.plugins.withId("org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform", pluginAction)
project.plugins.withId("org.jetbrains.kotlin.js", pluginAction)
// project.plugins.withId("kotlin2js", pluginAction) // maybe even `kotlin2js`
private class KotlinJsCompilerDisambiguationRule : AttributeDisambiguationRule<String> {
    override fun execute(details: MultipleCandidatesDetails<String>) {
        details.closestMatch("legacy")
    }
}
```

To apply the workaround, add the following snippet to your build.gradle file:

```
apply(from = "workaround_to_use_1_4_libs_in_1_3.gradle.kts")
```

i didnt find the solution I got pointed to it by some one in slack channel
you track link that has the solution

[the sloution link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-40226)